# How do I fix my rigidbody2d from stopping mid-air after a wall jump?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm pulling my hair out here. I just started programming, and I'm trying to make a simple character controller. My issue is that when the player preforms a wall jump,their velocity is overwritten and they stop mid-air. They stop when isWallJumping is set to false. I want the player to continue their velocity after isWallJumping is set to false.

Please forgive me for the horribly messy code, I don't know what I'm doing. Some of the stuff in there doesn't even do anything, I need to clean it up. It is also possible that I just need to completely rewrite this mess, if so please tell me. Thank you to anyone who helps me.

`public class MovementPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
public float raycastDistance;

```
public float speed;
private float move;
public float jump;
public float jump2;
public float jumpnum;
public float playerPos;
private bool isMoving;
public float smashForce;
private bool isSmashing;
public float leftCastDistance;
public float rightCastDistance;
public Vector2 rightBoxSize;
public Vector2 leftBoxSize;
private bool isWallLeft;
private bool isWallRight;
public float castDistance;
public bool isGrounded;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public Vector2 boxSize;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public Vector2 wallJumpForce;
public bool isWallJumping;
private float wallJumpDirection;
public float wallJumpDuration;
public float wallSlideSpeed;
public float maxClimbSpeed;
private bool isWallSliding;
private float wallJumpTimer = 0f;
public float maxSpeed;
// Start is called before the first frame update


private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position - transform.up * castDistance, boxSize);
    // Right BoxCast
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position + transform.right * rightCastDistance, rightBoxSize);

    // Left BoxCast
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position - transform.right * leftCastDistance, leftBoxSize);
}


void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.freezeRotation = true;
     
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (isWallJumping && wallJumpTimer <= 0f)
    {
        Vector2 tempForce = rb.velocity;
        stopWallJump();
        

    }
    else
    {
        wallJumpTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
    }





    wallSlide();
    
    wallJump();
    if (Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxSize, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
    {
        isWallJumping = false;
        isGrounded = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
    if (Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, rightBoxSize, 0, transform.right, rightCastDistance, groundLayer))
    {
        isWallRight = true;
        Debug.Log("wall right");
    }
    else
    {
        isWallRight = false;
    }
    if (Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, leftBoxSize, 0, -transform.right, leftCastDistance, groundLayer))
    {
        isWallLeft = true;
        Debug.Log("wall left");
    }
    else
    {
        isWallLeft = false;

    }




    if (isGrounded == true)
    {
        jumpnum = 0;
        isSmashing = false;
      
      
       
    }
    
    move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    
    if (!isWallJumping)
    {
        float maxForce = maxSpeed;
        Vector2 forceToAdd = new Vector2(speed * move - rb.velocity.x, 0f);
        forceToAdd = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(forceToAdd, maxForce);

        rb.AddForce(forceToAdd);
    }



    if (!isWallJumping)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if (jumpnum < 2)
            {
                if (isWallRight)
                {
                    isWallJumping = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (isWallLeft)
                    {
                        isWallJumping = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isWallJumping = false;
                        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0f);

                        if (jumpnum < 1)
                        {
                            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
                            jumpnum = jumpnum + 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump2));
                            jumpnum = jumpnum + 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isWallJumping)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            if (isGrounded == false)
            {


                if (isSmashing == false)
                {
                    Debug.Log("down");
                    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-rb.velocity.x, -smashForce));
                    isSmashing = true;
                    if (isSmashing == true)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("smash!");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

    isMoving = Mathf.Abs(move) > 0.01f;
}


private void wallJump()
{
    if (isWallSliding)
    {
        
        if (isWallRight)
        {
            wallJumpDirection = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (isWallLeft)
            {
                wallJumpDirection = 1;
            }
        }
      
    } 
    
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        if (isWallRight || isWallLeft)
        {


            if (jumpnum < 2)
            {
                isWallJumping = true;
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(wallJumpDirection * wallJumpForce.x, wallJumpForce.y));
                

            }
            wallJumpTimer = wallJumpDuration;
        }
       
    }
}

private void stopWallJump()
{
    Vector2 tempForce = rb.velocity;
    isWallJumping = false;
    rb.velocity = (tempForce);
}

private void wallSlide()
{
    if((isWallRight || isWallLeft) && !isGrounded && rb.velocity.x != 0f && !isWallJumping)
    {
        isWallSliding = true;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -wallSlideSpeed, maxClimbSpeed));
        if(rb.velocity.y == Mathf.Clamp(rb.velocity.y, -3, 0))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -3);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isWallSliding = false;
    }

   

}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!isMoving && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) > 0.01f)
    {
        float dampeningForce = rb.velocity.x * 0.5f;
        rb.AddForce(new Vector2(dampeningForce, 0f));


    }
}
```

}`

Comment: i see chaos!! OK there is a lot of missing info but one thing striking me is you call wallslide and walljump and then decide whether or not some of this is to be happening or not., also look into using the built in state machine to throw out some of this code and bring some sanity to yourself

Comment: It is a but too much to juggle with ~30 floats/bools nested in 6 "if" branching layers. It is normal to throw unsuccessfully attempts that became mess and start from scratch (sometimes 4-5 times). Start anew with different approaches. For the second attempt try to eliminate left/right variables and combine them together. It will still ended up  too complex to manage. Then on the third attempt try to lower the number of bools and if nesting. Separate  related parts in separate methods (and try variables to be used only in one method each), this will make your Update() easier to read and reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but your code is too messy to fix without a full rewrite.
Here are some directions if you are rewriting from scratch.

use `private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)`
to perform checks instead of doing `Physic2D.Box` cast in an `Update()`
I assume this is a 2D platformer, normally I would have a separate class entirely for checking because there are a lot of checking needed.
I like to keep the movement class clean by having it just dealing with movement and not the checking part.

I would use a simple state design pattern with `enum PlayerState = {ground, airborn, wallslide}` if this is a small project or a finite state machine pattern if it's an ambitious project with many different movement states. This approach makes it easier to keep track of the functionality of the code and allows for a smoother integration with an animator controller at a later stage.